# Using tensorflow.py_func in keras loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to use a python function 'IoU' as a keras loss function using tensorflow.py_func as follows:

```
def loss_fn(label, pred):
    return tensorflow.py_func(IoU, (label, pred), tf.float64)
```

But unfortunately, I got the following error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
```

I am using Keras 2.2.2 & tensorflow 1.10.0.

can you help me please to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider writing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This would greatly increase your odds of getting the right help for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to import the backend and then you can pass tensorflow functions directly. See https://keras.io/activations/ for details.